# Is it possible to ignore proximity device messages

Tags: c#, silverlight, nfc, windows-phone-8, ndef

i have to create a small app for recording NDEF tags and everything is going fine but there is one thing that drive me nuts. when the i put tag near the phone there is a message that apperars samething like this "Receive content?  some is sharing samething with you". Is it possible to ignore those kind of messages just for main page for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,  I don't think this possible. Such a message always appears when a tag is scanned,  irrespective of what app is running.

Comment: yeah but when i'm recording, and i place the tag, the message doesn't appear,this is strange for me

Comment: What do you mean by "recording"?

Comment: in one of my views i start publishing binary message and when a device enters the proximate range the procedure is completed

Comment: From what I saw, the message can still pop up, although the content will have been immediately overwritten by the publishing.

Comment: i have one one more problem i am trying to create ndef record for skype chat but my phone do not recognize it can i show it to you

Comment: Sounds more like you need to create another question on SO ;)